# Oracle Advanced Queueing - AccessViolationException in OracleClient

Tags: c#, oracle11g, access-violation, odp.net

I'm using Oracle Advanced Queueing in a .NET 4.5 Windows Service. The service should read from an Oracle Queue (11gR2) and process the messages in a transaction.
This works well for the first message in the queue, but when processing the second message a System.AccessViolationException is thrown deep inside the Oracle Client.

The service does the following things in a loop:

1. Start a new transaction (using TransactionScope)
2. Create a new OracleConnection
3. Create a new OracleAQQueue with this connection
4. Set the DequeueOptions.Wait property of the OracleAQQueue to 3
5. Open the OracleConnection
6. call Dequeue() on the OracleAQQueue
7. process the message using custom business logic
8. Complete (commit) the transaction from 1)
9. Dispose OracleAQQueue and OracleConnection

The first message in the queue will be processed, but in the next loop I get the following StrackTrace and the windows service is terminated:

```
System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OpsAQ.FreeCachedDesc(IntPtr ByRef, IntPtr ByRef, IntPtr ByRef)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OpsAQ.FreeCachedDesc(IntPtr ByRef, IntPtr ByRef, IntPtr ByRef)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleAQQueue.Dispose(Boolean)
   at StarTrack.Common.Messaging.AQ.InternalOracleQueue.Dispose()
   ....
```

I'm using Oracle Client 11.2.0.3.0 (64bit).

Update: also tried with the 12.1.0.1.0 (64bit) Client, same problem.

Has anybody done Oracle Advanced Queueing with similar problems and did solve it?

Best regards,
Markus

Comment: Why create instances of `OracleConnection` and `OracleAQQueue` to process only one message? Looks like only steps 6-8 belong in the loop, maybe step 1 also. I'd say you get `AccessViolationException`  because the Oracle client can only create one instance of the relevant object, which gets disposed at a nondeterministic time, even after the second instantiation. Because that's how garbage collection works.

Comment: Thank you @groverboy, I will give that a try. In the meanwhile I use this workaround which makes the system much more stable:

I disabled Oracle Client's connection pooling by adding `Pooling=false` in the connection string. Is a little bit slower now, but much more stable.

Comment: Okay, with connection pooling disabled there's less concurrency therefore less risk of error. It could be slower due to waiting for an exclusive connection. How do you know it's slower if previously it crashed on the second message?